# Observed "await is only valid in async function" error message when I tried to add response body into array list in Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I have a REST end point and trying to hit by using 'request' library in node.js by using the below file:

I just updated this question with latest observations.

Added new function called delayFunction() as below:

**Util.js**

```
  request = require('request')

  var delay1 = {
     delayFunction: function() {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function() {
        resolve(42); // After 3 seconds, resolve the promise with value 42
        }, 3000);
      });
    }
  }

    var getJSONValue1 = {

        getJSON: function(){

             let link=[];

             let file ="http://localhost:8080/idsearch/environment/amazon/cartId/2342cd1210a5";

             var headers ={
               "accept":"application/json"
             }

            var options = {
                url: file,
                headers: headers
            }

            request(options, function(error,response, body){

                 if(response.statusCode==200)
                   {
                    //return response.body {This is also not working} 
                     console.log('yes');
                     link.push(response.body);
                     await delay1.delayFunction();
                   }
            });

            console.log(link);

        }
    }

  module.exports = {

    getFunction: function(){
        return getJSONValue1.getJSON();
    }

 }
```

The above payload I'm trying to return the response body and printing into test.js file as below:

**test.js**

```
  var util = require(__dirname + '/util');

   let value=util.getFunction();

   console.log(value);
```

But I'm unable to get the response and It says undefined as below output.

**Output:**

```
[] 
undefined 
yes
```

**Updated Code:**

**Observed error:**

```
              await delay1.delayFunction();
                ^^^^^

              SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
```

Can anyone help me to get the response body which is only fly and store it into variable and use it for further reference.

Comment: Can you debug the code using console.log() right  after request(options, function(error,response, body){ console.log(response); console.log(error); console.log(body);  ....... } and please comment out await while debugging as it cause the error

Comment: I got the Payload when i use console.log(response.body); but its bit huge and taking time to print. The problem is unable to return it

Comment: What happen when return response.body  and comment out below codes, inside that block?

Comment: Can you explain your requirement in the question, from the code I understood you are trying to take data from a url on each time interval of 3 seconds. If you explain your requirement some one can give another alternate solution

Comment: I just want to return the response which is json format and stored into array or variable. I just want to loop that json to get value of some node . but i stuck to return the response itself. If i tried to write in fs it works fine but its taking time to write and this leads error to iterate the nodes in json. If i keep these two separate it works fine. But how can i achieve both all together .

Comment: In any case you should write "request(options, async function(error,response, body){..." to be able to use await.

Comment: It worked thanks vicraj...!!! Please post your answer I will accept it.